# Features of Windows Ad-hoc Network

Tags: wireless, ieee-802.11, internet, design, ad-hoc-wireless

Recently I was doing some tests in a small wireless ad-hoc network and one interesting feature I've found was:

- Suppose you have a hidden node problem among computers A, B and C (A and C are out of range from each other, but B can communicate with both). If A initialize the ad-hoc network and then B joined it, after that C would also be able to join it through B.

At first glance you might think that, as C could join the network created by A, probably C could also communicate with A (of course in a true ad-hoc network it doesn't matter who initiated it, this is just a fail-safe test). In that case, it means that this network has a multi-hop feature. However, this is not the case. Nodes can only communicate with other nodes within WiFi range, therefore, they don't participate in routing or forwarding data.

**1st Issue**
According to Wikipedia, in a wireless ad-hoc network "each node participates in routing by forwarding data for other nodes". How do we reconcile this definition with the current ad-hoc network of Windows? Technically, is it correct to call a single-hop network by ad-hoc? What features can we expect from the Windows Ad-hoc Network?

**2nd Issue**
What would be the technical challenges to develop a protocol for multi-hop ad-hoc network (if there is any)? Current computers would be too slow to forward data based on routing tables???

**3rd Issue**
If your computer has an Ethernet connection with the Internet and you setup a wireless ad-hoc network, you may share your internet connection within nodes in the ad-hoc network. However, the other nodes only in the ad-hoc network are not allowed to share such internet connectivity (a popup window appears complaining about a problem with automatic IP address).
What are the technical challenges to allow all nodes in an ad-hoc network to share internet connectivity (besides the multi-hop issue aforementioned)?

Comment: This is a question about consumer-grade devices (PCs running Windows) so it is off-topic here, but you can ask such a question on [su].

Comment: @RonMaupin I guess that the best people to answer this question are Network Engineers. I'm not sure that in 'Super User' people will be familiar with routing tables and multi-hop.

Comment: Many of the network engineers here are on Super User, too, but the question is off-topic here.

Comment: @RonMaupin Ok, just posted at 'Super User': [Features of Windows Ad-hoc Network](http://superuser.com/questions/1021025/features-of-windows-ad-hoc-network)

Comment: @RonMaupin By the way, do you have an website? (since there is no private message here)

Comment: No, I work for a very, very large company which has policies which make it difficult to do that.

Comment: @RonMaupin _No, I work for a very, very large company_ This is something I didn't understand yet how it works here in StackExchange: If users are not answering questions in order to promote their own businesses, what are the incentives to make them keep on answering questions?

Comment: This is complex, and I can't speak for everyone; this could be a question on Meta. Personally, I like to encourage the next generation of network engineers and learn from the problems and mistake that others share. If I can help someone and educate them, then I feel good about that. It goes back to the old parable about teaching a man to fish. I would like to believe that, if I run across a problem I just can't fix, I can reach out to someone else. Right now, I have the network vendors falling all over themselves to help me, but that may not always be the case.

Comment: @RonMaupin _I like to encourage the next generation_ Amazing how far StackExchange has gone with such altruistic model.

Answer (score 1):

The wikipedia description is wrong. In an ad-hoc network, nodes communicate directly. What they are describing is a *wireless mesh* network (aka: 802.11s).

Also, your understanding of ad-hoc is flawed. "A" doesn't "create the network". In an ad-hoc network, there are no controllers. Nodes communicate with each other directly, and independently. "A" may have been the first to broadcast, but that's irrelevant.

Comment: _In an ad-hoc network, there are no controllers._ I've just edited the question to avoid this issue.